# Problems with modal when deleting items in React apps

Tags: reactjs

I am learning about React and I am having problems when I want to delete an item with the axios DELETE method with my modal. Specifically, I want to click on the Delete icon to get the id to delete and when pressing confirm in the modal, it will send a request to the server. I got the id when I pressed the Delete icon but it seems the next step is not what I expected. Can you help me fix this problem? Thanks.
This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const UserItem = ({ user }) => {
  let userId = 0

  const getUserId = id => {
    userId = id;
  }

  const confirmDelete = () => {
   //axios({
   //  method: 'DELETE',
   //  url: `URL/${userId}`,
   //});
  console.log(userId);
  }

  return (
    <div className="row mx-0">
      <div className="cell">
        {user.name}
      </div>
      <div className="cell">
        {user.birthday}
      </div>
      <div className="cell">
        {user.email}
      </div>
      <div className="cell">
        {user.job}
      </div>
      <div className="cell">
        {user.company}
      </div>
      <div className="cell">
        {user.phone}
      </div>
      <div className="cell">
        <span title="Edit">
          <i className="far fa-edit"></i>
        </span>
        <span 
          title="Delete" 
          data-toggle="modal" 
          data-target="#exampleModal"
          onClick={() => getUserId(user.id)} 
        >
          <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
        </span>
      </div>


  <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex={-1} role="dialog" aria- 
   labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete user</h5>
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
          Are you sure ?
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={confirmDelete}>Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserItem;
```

Comment: _the next step is not what I expected_ - what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @suuuriam I am having the problem of not getting the right userId of each item I need. It always returns me as 0 while I have assigned the value of userId = id above

Comment: @suuuriam can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The most straightforward way is to pass the `user.id` to your `confirmDelete` function, as you do with your `getUserId` function: 
`onClick={confirmDelete(user.id)}`
An alternative would be to define `user.id` or an `user` object in the  state of your component: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Comment: Thank you, I have dealt with this problem.